# My Spring Application is running but css, js, and images are not being loaded

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, openshift

I have a problem with my Spring app that i'm deploying at OpenShift. Everything seems to be working except my static resource files (css, js, images). I'm getting the following error:

```
2015-12-11 12:46:31,302 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (de
fault task-2) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/resource/js/jquery-1.
11.3.min.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springDispatcher'
2015-12-11 12:46:31,395 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (de
fault task-3) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/resource/js/example.j
s] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springDispatcher'
2015-12-11 12:46:31,419 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (de
fault task-4) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/resource/css/example.
css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springDispatcher'
```

This is my Code:

```
@Order(1)
public class FrameworkBootstrap implements WebApplicationInitializer
{
    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException
    {
        log.info("Executing framework bootstrap.");

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = 
                new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(RootContextConfiguration.class);
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext servletContext = 
                new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        servletContext.register(ServletContextConfiguration.class);
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet(
                "springDispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(servletContext)
        );

        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");


        FilterRegistration.Dynamic registration = container.addFilter(
                "preSecurityLoggingFilter", new PreSecurityLoggingFilter()
        );
        registration.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
    }

}
```

And the config...

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(
        basePackages = "com.example.site",
        useDefaultFilters = false,
        includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(Controller.class)
)
public class ServletContextConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();

    @Inject ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    @Inject ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    @Inject Marshaller marshaller;
    @Inject Unmarshaller unmarshaller;
    @Inject SpringValidatorAdapter validator;

    @Bean
    public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/view/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        log.info("Adding Resource Handlers");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resource/**").addResourceLocations("/resource/");
        registry.setOrder(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }


    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(
            List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters
    ) {
        converters.add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
        converters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
        converters.add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
        converters.add(new SourceHttpMessageConverter<>());
        MarshallingHttpMessageConverter xmlConverter
                = new MarshallingHttpMessageConverter();
        xmlConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(
                new MediaType("application", "xml"),
                new MediaType("text", "xml")
        ));
        xmlConverter.setMarshaller(this.marshaller);
        xmlConverter.setUnmarshaller(this.unmarshaller);
        converters.add(xmlConverter);
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter
                = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        jsonConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(
                new MediaType("application", "json"),
                new MediaType("text", "json")
        ));
        jsonConverter.setObjectMapper(this.objectMapper);
        converters.add(jsonConverter);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.favorPathExtension(true).favorParameter(false)
                .parameterName("mediaType").ignoreAcceptHeader(false)
                .useJaf(false).defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .mediaType("xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .mediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    }

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> resolvers)
    {
        Sort defaultSort = new Sort(new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.ASC, "id"));
        Pageable defaultPageable = new PageRequest(0, 10, defaultSort);

        SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver sortResolver =
                new SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver();
        sortResolver.setSortParameter("paging.sort");
        sortResolver.setFallbackSort(defaultSort);

        PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver pageableResolver =
                new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver(sortResolver);
        pageableResolver.setMaxPageSize(100);
        pageableResolver.setOneIndexedParameters(true);
        pageableResolver.setPrefix("paging.");
        pageableResolver.setFallbackPageable(defaultPageable);

        resolvers.add(sortResolver);
        resolvers.add(pageableResolver);
    }

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry)
    {
        if(!(registry instanceof FormattingConversionService))
        {
            log.warn("Unable to register Spring Data JPA converter.");
            return;
        }

        DomainClassConverter<FormattingConversionService> converter =
                new DomainClassConverter<>((FormattingConversionService)registry);
        converter.setApplicationContext(this.applicationContext);
    }

    @Override
    public Validator getValidator()
    {
        return this.validator;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry)
    {
        super.addInterceptors(registry);

        registry.addInterceptor(new LocaleChangeInterceptor());
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        return new SessionLocaleResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestToViewNameTranslator viewNameTranslator() {
        return new DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator();
    }



}
```

The application is running, i'm just can't reach the files which are on the server in the following path.

src > main > webapp > resource > css > file.css

I can't find out what is wrong... Please Help!

Comment: Can you provide generated HTML source code?

Comment: And, how you reference from your JSP to resources? Something like: `<h:outputScript name="js/example.j
s" charset="UTF-8" />`